# How to assign a Gmail drive to a drive letter?

Tags: gmail

I would like to assign a drive letter to a GMail drive so that I could script some output to it.  Are they any hacks to get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GMail Drive no longer works (well) -- Google put rate limits into Gmail to prevent this kind of (ab)use of Gmail.  It's like being attached to a hard drive over a bad satellite connection to Rwanda*.

You might look into Amazon's S3, which is a cheap web-hosted data storage service; then ask this question again from an S3 perspective.

* Incidentally, that's what I deal with at work on a weekly basis.

Answer (score 1):

I use the SMEStorage service for this which works really well. The GMail package I signed up for enables you to use GMail as a Storage Cloud and it works really well. There are also some windows tools that you can use. I'm using the paid version which gives me a vitual (namespace) drive, sync, and shell tools as well as MS Office and Open Office integration. If sign up for the Lifetime Cloud package (which is what I did) you can use up to 10 GMail accounts.